# PHP login validation with session

Tags: php

I have this login form and a validation process. But even if the user exists my login form doesn't seem to work and errors wont pop up. I can't seem to find the problem. My validation and my form. I will show code from both files below.
The form in file name **login.php**

```
<div class="login-clean">
    <form method="post" action = 'plogin.php'>
        <h2 class="sr-only">Login Form</h2>
        <div class="illustration"><i class="icon ion-ios-navigate"></i></div>
        <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Е-маил"></div>
        <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Лозинка"></div>
        <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Најава</button></div><a href="#" class="forgot">Ја заборавивте лозинката? Кликнете овде.</a></form>
</div>
```

The validation in file name **plogin.php**

```
    session_start();
include('includes/general.php');
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $email);
    mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $password);
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connection));
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $user = $row['username'];
            $pass = $row['password'];
            $firstname = $row['firstname'];
            $lastname = $row['lastname'];
            $email = $row['email'];
            $phone = $row['phonenumber'];
            if(password_verify($password, $pass)) {
                $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
                $_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;
                $_SESSION['lastname'] = $lastname;
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['phonenumber'] = $phone;
                header('location: user.php');
            } else {
                echo "<script>alert('invalid username/password');
                window.location.href = 'login.php';</script";

            } 
        }
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('invalid username/password');
            window.location.href= 'index.php';</script>";
    }
} else {
    header('location: index.php');
}
```

Contents of general.php file.

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "inhouse") or die ('error' . mysqli_error($connection))
?>
```

Comment: Please share the contents of general.php file

Comment: @gurpreetsinghchahal <?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "inhouse") or die ('error' . mysqli_error($connection))
?>

Comment: password_verify function validates the stored hashed password against the plain text password. make sure the hashed password stored in DB was created using password_hash() function.

Comment: Reference links:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and
http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: @gurpreetsinghchahal They are made with that function.

Comment: post the output of 
echo "$password | $pass"; (Add this just before password_verify function call)

Comment: @gurpreetsinghchahal Found the problem so far. It seems that when i type in any username password it doesn't even check. It just goes to the final else and takes me to my index page. That means this condition is not True. if(isset($_POST['login'])

Answer (score 1):

2 problems:

1. POST values are available only if isset ($_POST['login']), but there's no login POST data in login.php
2. email value are read twice - first as $email = $_POST['email'] second as $email = $row['email'] - this will replace prevoius read post value

Comment: Should i remove the if statement and just do the validation?

Answer (score 0):

You have written in the code `if(isset($_POST['login'])) { //Something }.` But in the form, you don't have any field related to login. Debug your code you will get your answers. Further, you can check what fields you are getting by `print_r($_POST)` in plogin.php

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors in your code and that is why it is not working. I took time out to address some of the errors. They are as follows.

1. As some other answers have stated, your form doesn't have any `element` with the name `login`. So, instead of checking that `login` is set, you should check that `S_POST` is not empty.
2. From your script, once can assume that the variable `$connecttion` is set inside the file `'includes/general.php'`. If that is not the case, you can quickly connect to your database using `mysqli_connect()` and pass the relevant parameters which are as follows: `host`,`username`,`password`,`database`
3. When trying to login a user, we normally ask for two information: username/email and password, and then we search our database for any record that matches those values the user entered. However, your current script checks for only the email and this is a poor way to handle login as anyone can easily impersonate anybody once they know the other person's email address.

**Note:**
Before saving a user's password to your database, make a `hash` of that password. Passwords are meant to be secret information. Should someone hack into your system, they won't be able to interpret the passwords of your users before you hashed them before saving.

4. Lastly, this line `$_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array($result);` I took out the `while` loop. It is expected that only one user should be returned from the database as no two persons should have the same `email address`...(Make sure your email field is unique in your database). Since we are expecting only one user, It means that `mysqli_fetch_array($result)` should return only one result, thus no need to loop through with a `while` loop.

Goodluck.

The following should work with the html form that you have:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'testblog');
    if(!$connection){
        die("Failed to connect to database ".mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);
    $hashedPassword = hash('SHA256', $password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$hashedPassword'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connection));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        header('location: user.php');
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('invalid username/password');
            window.location.href= 'login.php';</script>";
    }
} else {
    header('location: index.php');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem is even when i write a correct username and password from db it still says that it is invalid username or password.

Comment: When you try to login from your form?

Answer (score 0):

One of many possible solution below.

```
<?php

session_start();
include('includes/general.php');

//read post data from login.php
if(isset($_POST['email']))    { $post_email    = $_POST['email'];    }
if(isset($_POST['password'])) { $post_password = $_POST['password']; }

//check post data, if missing return error
IF ((!empty($post_email)) || (!empty($post_password))) {
  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $post_email);
  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $post_password);
} else {
 echo "<script>
         alert('missing username/password');
         window.location.href = 'login.php';
       </script>";
}

//read user
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'database');
if(!$connection){
 die("Failed to connect to database ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connection));

//get number of results
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

//read result data
if ($num > 0) {

  if(password_verify($post_password, $pass)) {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     $id         = $row['id'];
     $user       = $row['username'];
     $pass       = $row['password'];
     $firstname  = $row['firstname'];
     $lastname   = $row['lastname'];
     $email      = $row['email'];
     $phone      = $row['phonenumber'];
   }

    $_SESSION['id']          = $id;
    $_SESSION['username']    = $user;
    $_SESSION['firstname']   = $firstname;
    $_SESSION['lastname']    = $lastname;
    $_SESSION['email']       = $email;
    $_SESSION['phonenumber'] = $phone;
    header('location: user.php');

  }

 }

}

echo "
 <script>
  alert('invalid username/password');
  window.location.href = 'login.php';
 </script>
";

?>
```